# Stacking the same lines into packet, and writing to new file

Tags: c#, .net, csv, readfile, writefile

I would like to know how to stack the same lines titled to packet and write to next file. For example, I had the following problem:

I read CSV file line by line, and I want to stack lines with the same titles to one packet.

file1:

```
Test;param1
Test;param2
Test1;param1
Test1;param2
Test1;param3
Test2;param1
```

result file:

```
Test;[param1,param2]
Test1;[param1,param2,param3]
Test2;[param1]
```

It does not have to be identical, but it is a hint on how to do something like that.

My code:

```
     var enumLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(pathZamowienia, Encoding.UTF8);
    int factor = 0;


    foreach (var line in enumLines)
    {
        var tabLine = line.Split(';').ToList();

        if (factor == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Title = tabLine[0];
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failure");
            }
            try
            {
                Param = tabLine[1];
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failure");
            }
            factor++;
        }
```

Comment: "I had the following problem: " this is not a problem in StackOverflow sense. It is a requirement. Please tell us the expected outcome and the actual outcome and describe the difference, which would be "the problem" in StackOverflow sense

Comment: What type of file should the result file be in? Anyways FWIW, I would create a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` to hold this data. You then could write all of this out after you've parsed it. There are other ways as well, just one solution.

Comment: it might be csv

Comment: @emias4 please update your post to include the actual issue you're facing, it's not clear.

Comment: _"stack lines with the same titles"_ sounds like [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results).  In fact, searching for _GroupBy_ and _CSV_ together produced lots of good search results for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LINQ query to group the lines

```cs
// Test input
var enumLines = new List<string> {
    "Test;param1",
    "Test;param2",
    "Test1;param1",
    "Test1;param2",
    "Test1;param3",
    "Test2;param1"
};

// Re-group the parameters
var newLines = enumLines
    .Select(s => s.Split(';'))
    .GroupBy(a => a[0], a => a[1])
    .Select(g => g.Key + ";[" + String.Join(",", g) + "]");

// Test output:
foreach (string line in newLines) {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Output:

> Test;[param1,param2]
> Test1;[param1,param2,param3]
> Test2;[param1]

Note that the group `g` itself is an enumeration of the aggregated values and also has a property `Key`. The first argument of `GroupBy` selects the Key, the second optional parameter selects the value to be aggregated. If it is omitted, the input (the string array `a`) is aggregated.

If the input includes misshaped lines, you could also exclude them with an additional Where-clause:

```cs
var newLines = enumLines
    .Select(s => s.Split(';'))
    .Where(a => a.Length >= 2)
    .GroupBy(a => a[0], a => a[1])
    .Select(g => g.Key + ";[" + String.Join(",", g) + "]");
```

Comment: Thanks, it is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do. Parse your file first and then transform

```
var data - new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

foreach(string line in Lines)
{
    string parts = line.Split(';');
    if (!data.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
        data.Add(parts[0], new List<string>());

    data[parts[0]].Add(parts[1]);
}

// then you open stream and write this

foreach(var kvp in data)
{
    string line = $"{kvp.Key};[{string.Join(',', kvp.Value)}]"
    //  write line here 

}

// close stream
```